# Me aparece este error y no sé como solucionarlo: Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.applyMiddleware()`

Tags: nodejs

estoy dando mis primeros pasos en programación y aún siguiendo paso a paso un video me sale un error (que al programador en el video no) y las respuestas buscadas con google no me funcionan, inclusive una en este sitio no responde a mi problema:

Archivo server.ts

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import express from "express";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { BookResolver } from "./resolvers/BookResolver";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
export async function startServer() {
  const app = express();
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({ resolvers: [BookResolver] }),
  });
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql" });
  return app;
}
```

Archivo book.resolver en carpeta resolvers

```
 import { Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";
    @Resolver()
    export class BookResolver {
      @Query(() => String)
      getAll() {
        return "All my books";
      }
    }
```

archivo main.ts

```
import { startServer } from "./server";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
async function main() {
  const port: number = 4000;
  const app = await startServer();
  app.listen(port);
  console.log("Hola Carolina espero que funcione runing on port:", port);
}
main();
```

El listado errores por consola que me aparece es:

> Error: You must `await server.start()` before calling `server.applyMiddleware()`
> at ApolloServer.assertStarted (C:\node-project\node_modules\apollo-server-core\src\ApolloServer.ts:621:13)
> at ApolloServer.applyMiddleware (C:\node-project\node_modules\apollo-server-express\src\ApolloServer.ts:71:10)
> at C:\node-project\src\server.ts:15:16
> at step (C:\node-project\src\server.ts:34:23)
> at Object.next (C:\node-project\src\server.ts:15:53)
> at fulfilled (C:\node-project\src\server.ts:6:58)
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: El error es bastante claro, y basta con revisar la [documentación](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/middleware/#apollo-server-express) (el ejemplo en específico) para ver que antes de poder usar el método `server.applyMiddleware()` debes inicializar la instancia con `await server.start()`, esto dentro de tu método `startServer()`.

Comment: ricardo-dlc y cómo quedaría el código si es bastante claro?

Comment: ¿Tuviste la oportuidad de revisar el ejemplo? Como mencioné en mi comentario anterior, la documentación explica que antes de poner a "escuchar" a tu servidor, deber de "iniciarlo". Esto lo puedes hacer dentro de tu función `startServer()` justo antes de `apolloServer.applyMiddleware()`. Sería algo como `await apolloServer.start()` y luego aplicas el middleware.